# How to migrate data from H2 database backup to mysql

Tags: mysql, migration, h2, database-backups

I have a backup of my old H2 database in file format mv.db. I changed my schema somewhat(some columns in some tables are renamed or removed). And I now use mysql instead of H2. My goal is to move the data to my new database but I could not find any information about this case.

Comment: You can't simply move a backup from one database engine to another. The binary backup formats are definitely not compatible, while sql backups are most likely not compatible due to sql syntax differences. The best course of action is to use some kind of an ETL tool that can handle both H2 and mysql and move the data across though that tool. No, I cannot recommend such tool for you as tool recommendations are explicitly off topic here on SO.

Comment: I have no idea whether it would work but you could try using the [PostgreSQL ODBC driver](https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html?highlight=odbc&search=odbc#odbc_driver) with the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard.